# Migrate data from azure Datalake to Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, migration, azure-data-lake

I'm using Azure, I have data on the datalake, and i have a mongodb on azure (mongodb version 5).
I want to migrate the data from datalake into mongodb, I was thinking to use azure data factory, but it support only Mongodb connector up to 4.2.
Is there way a good way to move data from datalake into mongodb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no other Azure service except ADF and Synapse which can migrate data from Azure Data Lake to MongoDB. The Azure Database Migration Service (DNS) is also not applicable in this case.

As a workaround, you can temporarily migrate the data using ADF from the data lake to MongoDB 4.2. Later, simply migrate it to MongoDB version 5 by creating a zipped backup and dump it into the new database.

Please refer to this article on [How to Migrate Data In MongoDB](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/live-data-migration-mongodb/) to know more.

Comment: thanks for your reply, maybe I will use scripts to achieve that